# how do I know number of padded space in ciphertext

Tags: encryption

Is that a way to find out how many padded space in ciphertext? I am using Rjindaal 256 bit encryption.

Problem: On decryption, I am getting error saying "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed". I am using same Initialization vector and encryption keys for both encryption and decryption.

Comment: Padding is added before encryption is performed, so in general you cannot determine the number of padding bytes that were added (because once encrypted, padding and non-padding bytes should be indistinguishable). It seems likely you're doing something else incorrectly during either encryption/decryption. Post your code and someone may be able to assist further.

Comment: Your first step is to ensure that both encryption and decryption methods are using the same padding.  Do not rely on defaults but explicitly set the padding -- you may need to consult the documentation.  If in doubt use PKCS5/PKCS7 padding.